# How to write the below query without union? or Can i write the below query with simple subquery or by using joins?

Tags: sql, querydsl

How to write the below query without union? or Can i write the below query with simple subquery or by using joins?
My requirement is i have to fetch the result using querydsl. As querydsl is not supporting union operation. I was thinking to write the below query with joins then call it using querydsl.
        //below query is used to fetch the fleet calendar details

```
    SELECT * FROM
              (SELECT V.ID AS VID,
                V.MODEL,
                V.VIN,
                V.EXTERIOR_COLOR,
                V.LICENSE_PLATE,
                V.CURRENT_LOCATION,
                V.NOTES,
                C.ID AS CID,
                //PFIS_COMMON_OPS.FORMATNAME concatnating the name
                PFIS_COMMON_OPS.FORMATNAME(C.FIRST_NAME,C.LAST_NAME,C.MIDDLE_NAME,2) AS JOURNALIST_NAME ,
                C.LICENSE_AFFI_NAME  AS AFNAME,
                L.DATE_OUT  AS DAYOUT,
                L.DATE_IN   AS DAYIN,
                NULL  AS HOLD,
                ''   AS REASONS,
                NULL AS ADATE,
                L.LOAN_TYPE_ID  AS TYPEID
              FROM PFIS_VEHICLE_DETAILS V,
                PFIS_CONTACT C,
                PFIS_VEHICLE_CONTACT_LOAN L
              WHERE C.ID          =L.CONTACT_ID
              AND V.ID            =L.VEHICLE_ID
              AND L.LOAN_TYPE_ID IN (1,5)
              AND ( L.DATE_IN BETWEEN TO_DATE('04/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('05/10/2014','DD/MM/YYYY')
              OR L.DATE_OUT BETWEEN TO_DATE('04/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('05/10/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'))
            -- AND LOWER(V.CURRENT_LOCATION) = 'new york'
              UNION
        --fetch from data for status-Id=5
              SELECT V.ID AS VID,
                V.MODEL,
                V.VIN,
                V.EXTERIOR_COLOR,
                V.LICENSE_PLATE,
                V.CURRENT_LOCATION,
                V.NOTES,
                0                  AS CID,
                ''                 AS JOURNALIST_NAME ,
                ''                 AS AFNAME,
                NULL               AS DAYOUT,
                NULL               AS DAYIN ,
                S.ON_HOLD_TILL     AS HOLD,
                S.REASONS_FOR_HOLD AS REASONS,
                S.ANTICIPATED_DATE AS ADATE,
                -1                 AS TYPEID
              FROM PFIS_VEHICLE_DETAILS V,
                PFIS_VEHICLE_DETAIL_STATUS S
              WHERE V.ID     =S.VEHICLE_ID
              AND S.STATUS_ID=4
              AND ( S.ANTICIPATED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('04/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('05/10/2014','DD/MM/YYYY')
              OR S.ON_HOLD_TILL BETWEEN TO_DATE('04/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('05/10/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'))
              --AND LOWER(V.CURRENT_LOCATION) = 'new york'
            )
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: format your query please

Comment: Does querydsl support `INCLUDE`?

Comment: No it does not support

Comment: Can we write the above query with simple joins??

Comment: Can we write the above query with simple joins(like equi-joins,left outer or  etc ) or subqueries?

Comment: QueryDSL **does** support `UNION`

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name : Could you pls provide me the sample code which supports union. Finally i wanted to write the above query in QueryDSL. I am new to QueryDSL, Could you pls help

Comment: @KavithaReddy It would have been nice of you to ask your real question from the start instead of wasting my time by providing misleading information.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=querydsl+union

Comment: @Craig: My apologies for misinterpretation.  I tried with Querydsl union it did not work for me. So i thought of to fine tune a query with simple joins. Actual need is i have to fetch the results from QueryDSL,  I am new QueryDSL, the implementation did not work for me. Its because of the version which we are using it or not am not sure. Instead wasting time on it, I wanted to give a try with Simple Joins. I tried from the below link:  https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/129

Comment: @KavithaReddy Read the very last comment on the page you linked (from **2012**). And apart from that, the issue on that post was asking about `UNION ALL` saying that `UNION` ***did*** work. You need to read the information you have more thoroughly if you want to make progress.

Answer (score 0):

If neither `UNION` nor `INCLUDE` supported, there isn't a simple answer.

The following changes to your FROM and WHERE clauses should do the trick. **NOTE** I highly recommend you get into the habit of using `JOIN` clauses rather than mixing join conditions and filters in your `WHERE` clause. It's a little more verbose, but much easier to read and spot mistakes if you use decent formatting.

> Bear in mind this is making an assumption because you haven't provided sample data: each `PFIS_VEHICLE_DETAILS` row appears at most once in either the first part of the union, or the second; never both. Otherwise you have to work a bit more to get your rows to double up when necessary.

```
FROM    PFIS_VEHICLE_DETAILS V
        /* First part of union. LEFT JOIN bc presumably rows aren't expected to match rows from second part of union. */
        LEFT JOIN (
                /* Use subquery to filter bc values would be NULL in non matching rows. */
                SELECT  *
                FROM    PFIS_VEHICLE_CONTACT_LOAN L
                WHERE   L.LOAN_TYPE_ID IN (1, 5)
                    AND (   L.DATE_IN BETWEEN TO_DATE('04/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('05/10/2014','DD/MM/YYYY')
                        OR  L.DATE_OUT BETWEEN TO_DATE('04/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('05/10/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'))
                ) L ON
            V.ID = L.VEHICLE_ID
        LEFT JOIN PFIS_CONTACT C ON
            C.ID = L.CONTACT_ID
        /* Second part of union */
        LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    PFIS_VEHICLE_DETAIL_STATUS S
                WHERE   S.STATUS_ID=4
                    AND (   S.ANTICIPATED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('04/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('05/10/2014','DD/MM/YYYY')
                        OR  S.ON_HOLD_TILL BETWEEN TO_DATE('04/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('05/10/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'))
                ) S ON
            V.ID = S.VEHICLE_ID
```

If the above doesn't work, there is a convoluted approach to simulate `UNION` using `FULL OUTER JOIN` which could be applied more generally. *But it gets messy* - to the point where you may want to consider whether you're using the right tool for the job; i.e. ditch the tool in favour of something that *does* support UNION.

The approach is to use `FULL OUTER JOIN` to construct a result-set combining the 2 union-parts (we'll call U1 and U2) similar to the following:

```
U1.C1 U1.C2 U2.C1 U2.C2 JOIN_COL
1-1   xx    NULL  NULL  U1
1-2   yy    NULL  NULL  U1
1-3   zz    NULL  NULL  U1
NULL  NULL  2-1   aa    U2
NULL  NULL  2-2   bb    U2
NULL  NULL  2-3   cc    U2
```

Then you merge `U1.C1` with `U2.C1` and similarly `U1.C2` with `U2.C2`.

The structure of your query would be similar to the following:

```
SELECT  u1.C1, u1.C2, u2.C1, u2.C2, COALESCE(u1.JOIN_COL, u2.JOIN_COL) as JOIN_COL
FROM    (   /* JOIN_COL is important as it allows joining U1 and U2 without matching rows */
            SELECT  'U1' as JOIN_COL,
                    C1, C2, ...
            FROM    ... 
        ) u1 /* Subquery for part of "union" */
        FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT  'U2' as JOIN_COL,
                    C1, C2, ...
            FROM    ... 
        ) u2 ON /* Subquery for part of "union" */
            u1.JOIN_COL = u2.JOIN_COL
```

The given `SELECT` demonstrates the first part of the object. Replace that with the following to get the final simulated UNION.

```
SELECT  COALESCE(u1.C1, u2.C1) as C1,
        COALESCE(u1.C2, u2.C2) as C2,
        ... /* Note JOIN_COL obviously not needed in final output */
```

Comment: I tried the first query its not working for me. Query Results are not matching with union and joins.

Comment: @KavithaReddy Well, you haven't provided sample data in your question, so I cannot see what's wrong. I have assumed your UNION would be equivalent to UNION ALL. And that in the UNION case, each Vehicle_Details is supposed to be represented only once; either from the top part of the UNION or the bottom part.